# Размещение изображения в верхней части приложения

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlayout, qlabel

Как расположить изображение *в верхней части* приложения так, 
чтобы внизу осталось место для размещения других виджетов?

Ниже скрин окна приложения. Под изображением есть место для виджетов, но сверху оно не закреплено к верхней части окна.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap("oreh.jpg")
        lbl = QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.move(100, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('oreh')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication,
                             QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui  import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('oreh')
        self.resize(500, 400)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        pixmap = QPixmap("Ok.png")
        lbl = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(lbl)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        vbox.addStretch()            # <---

        self.setLayout(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**подскажи, чтобы растянуть это изображение по ширине окна, 
мне нужно использовать методы изменения размера для pixmap или для lbl?**

> QLabel::setScaledContents(bool)
>
> Это свойство определяет, будет ли метка масштабировать свое содержимое, 
>   чтобы заполнить все доступное пространство. 
>   Если этот параметр True-включен и метка отображает растровое изображение, 
>   оно масштабирует растровое изображение, чтобы заполнить доступное пространство. 
>   По умолчанию это свойство имеет значение False.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication,
                             QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtGui  import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('oreh')
        self.resize(500, 400)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        pixmap = QPixmap("Ok.png")
        lbl = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        lbl.setScaledContents(True)                       # < ---

        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(lbl)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        vbox.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: подскажи, чтобы растянуть это изображение по ширине окна, мне нужно использовать методы изменения размера для ```pixmap``` или для ```lbl```? С ```pixmap``` не нашел.

Comment: @ShevIv я добавил пример и некоторые пояснения.